# Change frames of UILabel using Auto layouts based

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, uilabel

I have 2 UILabels in a view, Upper label is multiline and bottom is single line.

Case 1 : I want to show both labels. (Currently working fine)

Case 2 : I only want to show Upper label but text in centre of view (Having issue here)

Please look at the images for more understanding.

Upper Label constraints as below.
[image]

Bottom Label constraints as below.

[image]

Case 2 which I want to achieve. 
[image]

Currently in case 2, text starts from upper left corner. If text is too small it docent look good. What should I do to achieve case 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by `AutoLayout constraints`, you can follow one of two approaches

1. Add Height constraint on both labels and and create `IBOutlet` for both constraints and in side code when you want to use height set `oneLabelHeightConstraint.constant = <value you want>` or and set other label `heightConstraint.constatn = 0`
2. Pin topLabel bottom with `bottomLabel` `top` and then add `height` constraint on `bottomLabel` and when you want to show `topLabel` set `bottomLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0`.